# Window function and conditional filters in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, window-functions

Is there a way to conditionally apply filter to a window function in pyspark? For every group in `col1` I want to keep only rows that have `X` in `col2`. If a group doesn't have `X` in `col2` I want to keep all rows in that group.

```
+------+------+
| col1 | col2 |
+------+------+
| A    |      |
+------+------+
| A    | X    |
+------+------+
| A    |      |
+------+------+
| B    |      |
+------+------+
| B    |      |
+------+------+
| B    |      |
+------+------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a `max` window function to denote the group (partitioned by col1) which has 'X' in col2 with an identifier (1 in this case). Groups which don't have 'X' will get assigned `null`. Thereafter just filter the intermediate dataframe to get the desired result.

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import max,when
w = Window.partitionBy(df.col1)
df_1 = df.withColumn('x_exists',max(when(df.col2 == 'X',1)).over(w))
df_2 = df_1.filter(((df_1.x_exists == 1) & (df_1.col2 == 'X')) | df_1.x_exists.isNull())
df_2.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative using `collect_list` with more SQL syntax: `NULL` value is skipped for collect_list, we use `if(col2='X',1,NULL)` as list item so that when no 'X' is shown in col2, size of this collect_list is ZERO:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr                                                                              

df_new = df.withColumn('has_X', expr("size(collect_list(if(col2='X',1,NULL)) OVER (partition by col1))>0")) \
           .filter("col2 = 'X' OR !has_X")
```